# How to Instantiate a Gameobject as a child in a Queue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to instantiate a gameobject in a Queue as a child of a gameobject in unity
Thanks

```
  void SpawnSolders()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < warriorsCount; i++)
        {
            if (isOcupied[i] == false)
            {
                isOcupied[i] = true;
                warriorsQ.Enqueue((GameObject)Instantiate(war1, battlePositions[i].position, transform.rotation));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#` (don't spam all version though .. this is most probably not `c#-2.0`) .. also just because you use a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't automatically make your question about that IDE in specific. You should though add the `unity3d` tag since that is the main framework/ API you are asking about

Comment: And .. what exactly is not working in your current code? `Instantiate` takes a parameter `Transform parent` .. you are not passing it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass parent parameter to Instantiate function.

```
void SpawnSolders()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < warriorsCount; i++)
    {
        if (isOcupied[i] == false)
        {
            isOcupied[i] = true;
            warriorsQ.Enqueue((GameObject)Instantiate(war1, battlePositions[i].position, transform.rotation, parentGameObject.transform));
        }
    }
}
```